# How to filter distinct values for a kusto column

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I want to keep distinct values for the given column. Assume I have the following columns out of which I want distint values for the column Values. Here is the input

```
Name       Values      Desc
B          "1,2,1,3"   Sample desc 1
A          "3,1,3"     Sample desc 2
A          "4"         Sample desc 3
```

This is the output I`m expecting:

```
Name       Values      Desc
B          "1,2,3"     Sample desc 1
A          "3,1"       Sample desc 2
A          "4"         Sample desc 3
```

I have this query in place:

```
Table
| project Name, Values, Desc
```

Please help with how to modify this kusto query to return the desired output.

Comment: What's the point of getting it back to a string form with qualifiers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
datatable(Name:string, Values:string, Desc:string)
[
    'B' ,'"1,2,1,3"' ,"Sample desc 1"
   ,'A' ,'"3,1,3"'   ,"Sample desc 2"
   ,'A' ,'"4"'       ,"Sample desc 3"
]    
| extend Values = strcat_array(set_union(split(trim('"', Values), ","), dynamic([])), ",")
```

| Name | Values | Desc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | 1,2,3 | Sample desc 1 |
| A | 3,1 | Sample desc 2 |
| A | 4 | Sample desc 3 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA2XPsQrCMBAG4D1PcdySFLK0dRIcFGcXwaWUcjZBAkksTQoWfHjTEgX1Agf/8Q1/FMX0rlaLEzm9DXE0/ibhQnbS4ROPOvQ5FKxhkIYfOEiOpaxkKWtMAc/kBqtBJQwlLkry/arqbOBHVV9qswr4UzWydrmyJ%20hH1F7lerCD1Kmn2NE40iyCjt3kzd2LMFgTRerrBEf%20/k4hASWmrWZPzvSiaYt8ewHC46e7BwEAAA==)

Answer (score 1):

```
datatable(Name:string, Values:string, Desc:string)
[
    'B' ,'"1,2,1,3"' ,"Sample desc 1"
   ,'A' ,'"3,1,3"'   ,"Sample desc 2"
   ,'A' ,'"4"'       ,"Sample desc 3"
]    
| extend Values = set_union(parse_json(strcat("[", trim('"', Values), "]")), dynamic([]))
```

| Name | Values | Desc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | [1,2,3] | Sample desc 1 |
| A | [3,1] | Sample desc 2 |
| A | [4] | Sample desc 3 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA2XPsQrCMBAG4D1PcdySBG5p6yQ4KM4ugkspJTaHVJpYmhQUfHjTUgU1GS7/8Q1/rInpnjtWB+N4HeLQ+gvByXQjh0/cc2iWoEUpIB25k0ASM8opowJTwKNxfcdgE4YMJ0VyO6tiMfCj8i+1mgX8qQJFNW3FE/ge2dulHmwgcKxH39686s0QuL6G9ExFGxMVlkiQOjslUb6/pAmwQp2GfXjj2kaVldYv8Q1D6AYBAAA=)

Answer (score 1):

```
datatable(Name:string, Values:string, Desc:string)
[
    'B' ,'"1,2,1,3"' ,"Sample desc 1"
   ,'A' ,'"3,1,3"'   ,"Sample desc 2"
   ,'A' ,'"4"'       ,"Sample desc 3"
]    
| mv-apply num = extract_all(@"(\d+)", Values) on (summarize Values = make_set(toint(num)))
```

| Name | Desc | Values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | Sample desc 1 | [1,2,3] |
| A | Sample desc 2 | [3,1] |
| A | Sample desc 3 | [4] |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA2XOwQrCMAwG4HufIvTSFuthmydBUPHsRfCiMqILMmy7sXai4sPbjSmoyekPX0IKDLGPhuQaLU19aEp31rBF05L/xBX50xAU2zGIJZYCtOCJTnWiMx4D36CtDUERMSS8U1osepUNBn5U+qUmvYA/lXF26KbsCfY6xro2d3CthRnQLTR4CjkaI+dc7ouR4u/nFVQOpG+txaZ80DCNSxYvlHsKMlSlCzJeUkq9AKszVuUIAQAA)